# CSS Slideshow not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am a little stuck trying to get the following code to behave properly in Firefox, it works fine in Chrome, but does not work in firefox, if someone can help I will be delighted.

**CSS**

```
.SlidingPhotoFrame{ max-width:100%;  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #bbe3ff; padding:5px; margin-bottom:10px;  background-color:white; }

.SlidingPhoto { 
padding-top: 50.20%;  /* 450px/800px = 0.5625 */
margin:0; text-align:center; 

background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG)) center top no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */

animation-name:PhotoFrames;
animation-duration:20s;
animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
animation-delay:0s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-play-state:running;

    /* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name:PhotoFrames;
-webkit-animation-duration:20s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}


@keyframes PhotoFrames
{
0%   {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
23%  {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

25%  {background:url(Slideshow/2.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
47%  {background:url(Slideshow/2.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

50%  {background:url(Slideshow/3.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
74%  {background:url(Slideshow/3.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

75%  {background:url(Slideshow/4.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
97%  {background:url(Slideshow/4.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

100%  {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes PhotoFrames /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
23%  {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

25%  {background:url(Slideshow/2.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
47%  {background:url(Slideshow/2.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

50%  {background:url(Slideshow/3.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
74%  {background:url(Slideshow/3.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

75%  {background:url(Slideshow/4.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
97%  {background:url(Slideshow/4.JPG) center top no-repeat; }

100%  {background:url(Slideshow/1.JPG) center top no-repeat; }
}
```

** HTML **

```
<div class="SlidingPhotoFrame">
  <figure class="SlidingPhoto"></figure>
</div>
```

If there's a better way to do the same thing, please suggest, I like to keep the code as simple as possible, whenever possible.  Haven't checked for Safari or IE yet...  Any suggestions for that also would be great.

Comment: A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: Here it is in the 'wild'

http://www.poipleshadow.com/

Comment: I see `@-webkit-keyframes`, but I don't see `@-moz-keyframes`... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can review the below sample which based on modern cross-browsers.
I think you need to use -moz prefix in order to work on Mozilla Firefox.

```
-moz-animation-name:PhotoFrames;
-moz-animation-duration:20s;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-delay:0s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-play-state:running;
```

Please refer to this one on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kirkian/DCMzS/)

Comment: I fiddled with your jsfiddle and added it to my code, but still doesn't seem to work, displays first image but doesn't change to the next ones. :S

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Demo, please use it with your images for better view. [Here is a JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/99LDe/12/).

Use this CSS code and HTML Code:

```
<div class="SlidingPhotoFrame">
  <figure class="SlidingPhoto"></figure>
</div>


.SlidingPhotoFrame{ max-width:100%;  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #bbe3ff; padding:5px; margin-bottom:10px;  background-color:white; }

.SlidingPhoto { 
padding-top: 50.20%;  /* 450px/800px = 0.5625 */
margin:0; text-align:center; 

background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center top no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */

animation-name:PhotoFrames;
animation-duration:20s;
animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
animation-delay:0s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-play-state:running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    /* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name:PhotoFrames;
-webkit-animation-duration:20s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes PhotoFrames
{
0% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -100px;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    75% {
        background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center top no-repeat;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 100px;
    }

    100% {
        background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) center top no-repeat;
        opacity: 0;
        left: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: this is fiddle link.. while posting link I always get error. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/99LDe/12/

Comment: @Poiple Shadow is this solution work for you? link posted on above comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because Firefox does not support animations on background images. Background-image is not animatable. Chrome has its own implementation but you won't get it working Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties